# How to highly customize Magento sales e-mail template with some PHP rules?

Tags: magento

I need to put the name of the products (courses) bought by the customer only on the email sent after payment confirmation.

But e-mail templates, as far as i know, doesn't accept PHP codes to do some rules.

What I need is something like

```
Congratulations,
Your subscription for Course 1, Course 4 and Course 8 is confirmed.
```

So, I guess I will need to get the products, put them into a string, etc...

How can I get it work this way? Is there a way to split the ordered products and make these php rules inside Transactional Emails CMS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Magento is already doing something like this.

Ref:

Default shipment email template, [app/locale/en_US/template/email/sales/shipment_new.html](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/locale/en_US/template/email/sales/shipment_new.html#L98):

```
{{layout handle="sales_email_order_shipment_items" shipment=$shipment order=$order}}
{{block type='core/template' area='frontend' template='email/order/shipment/track.phtml' shipment=$shipment order=$order}}
```

Processed in [`Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Filter::layoutDirective()`](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php#L200) and [`::blockDirective()`](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php#L156).

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial nails it:

http://www.webspeaks.in/2011/06/customize-new-order-email-template-in.html

You get $order available in a phtml file where you can put together the php needed for you to get what you are looking to achieve.

Comment: Broken link. From http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer : "Provide context for links

Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."